# Why does jsfiddle ignore gist css files?

Tags: css, resources, jsfiddle

Adding a gist css-file to jsfiddle by "Add Resources" url does not seem to work.
Am I missing something or is it not supported?

Fiddle that does not load from url:

http://jsfiddle.net/keffot/dpWWz/

Fiddle with css content copied to css-frame:

http://jsfiddle.net/keffot/DTFfK/

Comment: Maybe because of `https` in your link? Try to use not secure link.

Comment: I tried to change the url to plain http url but it did not work though. Think I go for the dropbox solution temporarly.

Comment: Try to open your link in browser - it will redirects to `https` again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. The problem is in the `https`. I've added the same file but from my dropbox public folder and here is result: http://jsfiddle.net/dpWWz/3/

Link to the file is: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/18372729/page-layout.css

Comment: Seems that gist css-files can't be used with jsfiddle so I'll stick with the public drop-box solution. Thanks again for the tip!